# Why is my check constraint not allowing me to add any more values to my table?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

```
alter table historicfirstnames with nocheck
add constraint numberoffirstnames check(dbo.countoffn() < 2) 
go
alter function countoffn()
returns int
as 

begin
return 
(select max(w.cf) from (select count(firstname) as cf from historicfirstnames group by firstname) as w)

end

create table simpleversionofsqlproject
(firstname varchar(5),
lastname varchar(5)
)
go

create table historicfirstnames
(
firstname varchar(5)
)
```

this is the procedure with which i'm executing it:

```
decision  'ron','haller','insert'


alter procedure decision (@gt varchar(max) = null, @gg varchar(max) = null , @decision varchar(max))
as
begin

if @decision = 'select'
begin try
select *
from simpleversionofsqlproject
where firstname = isnull(@gt, firstname)
or lastname = isnull(@gg, lastname)
end try
begin catch
raiserror ('not here',16,1)
end catch



if @decision = 'update'
begin
begin try
update simpleversionofsqlproject 
set firstname = @gt, lastname =@gg 
where @gg = lastname or @gt =firstname
end try
begin catch
begin
throw
print 'you have made a mistake'

end
end catch

end

if @decision = 'insert'
begin
begin try
begin transaction
insert into simpleversionofsqlproject(firstname,lastname)
values( @gt, @gg)

insert into historicfirstnames
values (@gt)
commit transaction
end try
begin catch
rollback
print 'tata'
end catch
end

if @decision = 'delete'
begin
delete from simpleversionofsqlproject
where firstname = @gt
end

if @decision not in ('update','delete','insert','select')
begin
raiserror('wrong action',16,1)
end


end
```

this is the result:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
tata
```

Comment: You should use a unique constraint not a check constraint for this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your check constraint is allowing you to add new rows so long as no existing `firstname` is duplicated.

Once a first name is duplicated, no more rows can be added -- because you are looking at *all* first names, not just the one being inserted.  You have used the `no check` option, so I assume there are duplicates in the table.

You would need to pass `firstname` to the function and use it for a "unique" constraint.  But, why not just create a unique constraint?

```
alter table historicfirstnames with nocheck
    add constraint unq_numberoffirstnames unique(firstname);
```

Comment: what if it was 3 instead of 2 though?

Comment: @witchieleaks . . . I don't know what your data looks like.  But why not use a `unique` constraint if you want to enforce uniqueness?  I'm guessing that is what you really want to do.

Comment: create table simpleversionofsqlproject
(firstname varchar(5),
lastname varchar(5)
)
go

create table historicfirstnames
(
firstname varchar(5)
)